# VBA-Excel Rearrange columns in alphabetical order when new column is added

Tags: excel, vba

I´m having issues on my file when adding a new column through VBA. When clicking on a button it gets a process ID number and creates a column on table from a different sheet.

How can I rearrange the columns order alphabetically (By header value) each time a new column is added.

The number of columns is dynamic and I can´t know the header name until the user creates a process.

This is my current code:

```
'Create a new column on the process assignment table
Sheets("T_PRAS").ListObjects("T_PRAS").ListColumns.Add.Name = "PR_" & Sheets("Administrador").Range("B53").Value
```

Comment: Record a macro while sorting the table (use the "Sort left to right" option) and use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mildly tested, but I've done a similar thing when sorting worksheets and this appears to work with your table as well.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T_PRAS")

' Loop through each column
With tbl.ListColumns
    For x = 1 To tbl.ListColumns.Count
        For y = x + 1 To tbl.ListColumns.Count
            If .Item(y).Name < .Item(x).Name Then
                .Item(y).Range.Cut
                .Item(x).Range.Insert xlRight
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End With
```

Essentially, you have two loops. The first loop is comparing the column name with the second, and if the name of the 2nd loop comes before the first, then it will move that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim obj As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Set Ws = Sheets("T_PRAS")
    Set obj = Ws.ListObjects("T_PRAS")
    Set rng = obj.DataBodyRange.CurrentRegion
    With Ws.Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```